# sending Data to a REST Controller using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, reactjs, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to submit a small table of data to my REST endpoint using Ajax but I am not getting the results in the backend code.

Below is my Ajax request :

```
checkOut:function(){
var self = this;
var str = "junk string";
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:9000/checkoutcart/data/",
  type : "get",
  data : {
    ajaxid: 4, 
    UserID: str
    },
}).then(function (data) {    
  self.setState({movies: data});
});
cartItems.length = 0;
this.purchase = "Your shopping was successful";
```

},

Below is my Java controller code :

```
@GetMapping("/checkoutcart/{data}")
public void checkOutCart(@PathVariable String data){
    System.out.println("-->" + data);
}
```

However I do not get any output for data variable in my Java code.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is a good practice to use POST requests when submitting data to a Rest Service. I am not 100% sure, but your answer may be this one:

```
@PostMapping("/checkoutcart")
public String checkOutCart(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {
    System.out.println("AjaxID: " + params.get("ajaxid"));
    System.out.println("UserID: " + params.get("UserID"));
}
```

Comment: thanks dear. it works. I will accept the answer in 5 minutes :-)

Comment: I am really happy it did :D This is actually my first accepted answer :D